# AS3 strange error, gotoAndStop not working on first element of for loop

Tags: actionscript-3

```
function generateTiles()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (var k:int = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            var tile:Tiles = new Tiles();
            tile.x = 100 + k * tile.width;
            tile.y = 100 + i * tile.height;

            tile.gotoAndStop(1);

            addChild(tile);

            if (i == 0 && k == 0)
            {
                trace("is first tile on stage = " + contains(tile));
                trace("first tile frame = " + tile.currentFrame);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does tile.gotoAndStop(1); is not working for the first element ?

Code:

[image: code]

Result:

[image: result]

Full code:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Magipo extends MovieClip
    {
        var objGameRemoves:Array = new Array();

        var level:Array = new Array();

        public function Magipo()
        {
            startGame();
        }

        function startGame()
        {
            setPosition();
            setLevel();
            generateTiles();

        }

        function generateTiles()
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < level.width; i++)
            {
                for (var k:int = 0; k < level.height; k++)
                {
                    var tile:Tiles = new Tiles();
                    tile.x = 100 + k * tile.width;
                    tile.y = 100 + i * tile.height;

                    addChild(tile);
                    tile.gotoAndPlay(1);

                    if (i == 0 && k == 0)
                    {
                        trace("is first tile on stage = " + contains(tile));
                        trace("first tile frame = " + tile.currentFrame);
                        trace("x= " + tile.x + " y= " + tile.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function setPosition()
        {

        }

        function setLevel()
        {
            level.width = 10;
            level.height = 10;
            level.level = 
            ["2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2",
            "2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
            "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"];
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Is this behavior is fired every time you test your project ? Try to put `addChild(tile);` before the `tile.gotoAndStop(1);` and clear publish cache and test again.

Comment: Thank you for answer, akmozo, tried your suggestions, but I still have this problem. I get this every time I test the project. It's just strange

Comment: Could you share your fla ?

Comment: Your code is fine, that's why I told you to share your fla. And which Flash and Flash Player versions are you using ?

Comment: Thank you, I solved it, I was calling startGame(), but  I was exporting movie clip in frame 5, so I wasn't yet on frame 5 when startGame was called.